# Mod_rewrite for multiple ids and areas

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

forgive me but I'm pretty useless with mod_rewrite and could with a hand with something.

Basically, right now I have my page reflecting the page ID in a way similar to this:

http://www.url.com?id=X

Where X = whatever the ID is.

However, I need it to look like this:

http://www.url.com/AreaName

Where AreaName is a local area (e.g. /London).

I have about 30 areas, all with different names and of course IDs, how would I do a rewrite that reflects all /AreaName's to their relevant IDs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you access to your Apache config?

Comment: Yes. I'm working locally with Apache and MySQL but I'm about to but it onto the server but the site pretty much won't work until this final piece of the puzzle is done (all the URLs around the site are /AreaName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use [**`RewriteMap`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for your requirement. Here is an example how to use it:

1. Add following line to your `httpd.conf` file:

   ```
   RewriteMap areaMap txt://path/to/areaMap.txt
   ```
2. Create a text file as `/path/to/areaMap.txt` like this:

   ```
   London 1
   Paris 2
   Moscow 3
   ```
3. Add these line in your .htaccess file under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ID= [NC]
   RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2?ID=${areaMap:$1} [L,QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ID= [NC]
   RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ /?ID=${areaMap:$1} [L,QSA,NC]
   ```

**Advantage:** With this setup in place, you can edit or recreate the file `/path/to/areaMap.txt` anytime you have a new area-id mapping without any need to add new rules.

Comment: right, firstly, thank you! It's worked absolutely perfect (for what I've asked) but now I have a separate issue which I guess I should have explained.

Each area needs to then map to it's relevant page, like so:

http://www.url.com/AreaName/Page1.php

but the way it works is like this

http://www.url.com/Page1.php?id=X

So how can I change the rewrite to reflect each page and area? If that makes sense

Comment: also, some of the AreaNames contain hyphens are do not work with this current rewrite - any idea how to fix that? Thanks again

Comment: Ok just updated the code, it should meet both requirements now.

Comment: Apologies anubhava, this doesn't work now, I will try and be more clear, I really, really appreciate your help with this!

I need a rewrite that will do the following:

http://www.url.com?id=X -> http://www.url.com/AreaName (worked first time but no longer works after your update)

http://www.url.com/page?id=X -> http://www.url.com/AreaName/page

Page will vary, sometimes it will be page1, sometimes it may be page2, sometimes page3. It just needs to take the id of X and map it to an area (like you did).

Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: if it is easier for you, I can change the id to be the URL. E.g. www.url.com?id=AreaName -> www.url.com/AreaName or www.url.com/page.php?id=AreaName -> www.url.com/AreaName/page.php

Comment: Works fine but now the pages aren't loading correctly, it's almost as if the CSS and JS links are no longer working?

Comment: For CSS, JS etc make sure to use absolute URLs i.e. starting with `/` or `http://`

Comment: when I view source it is going to the correct url in the code but it says it cannot be found, are you sure it's not to do with this?

Comment: it is redirecting the URL from /css/style.css to /style.css

Comment: brilliant!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I am over the moon, if you'd like to see, visit http://puzzle-plumbers.com/ :) thank you again, you are great! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!

Comment: Ah, hate to be a pain but it's not quite there just yet! When I go on a local area the CSS isn't working again. See http://www.puzzle-plumbers.com/bletchley/central-heating.php for example.

Comment: It is the same problem I explained earlier. Your css code is: `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` i.e. using **relative path**. I commented above: `For CSS, JS etc make sure to use absolute URLs i.e. starting with / or http://`

Comment: oops, how embarrassing, the file reverted to a previous upload - sorted, fixed, sorry for wasting your time, thank you again.

Comment: Sure, no problem at all :)